# RST packet sent by the server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tcp

I am developing a client in Flash and using http req/resp to communicate with the server. For a while the session works fine and then the connection is terminated by the server. I did a wireshark sniff at the server and the last message which it sends is a RST packet. Also it happens only when I'm using IE and the server and client are in different domains. This does not happen in FireFox. I have been struggling to find a sol, till I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251243/what-causes-a-tcp-ip-reset-rst-flag-to-be-sent). It's a bit old but I hope I could get some help.
I am not sure if this bit of info is important but I am connecting to the server via a gateway.

Any clue or suggestions for where should I look into to locate the problem ?

Comment: What is "this thread" that you are referring to?

Comment: I added a link to the thread in question.

Comment: thnx for adding the link Bill, any suggestions. earlier i was thinking that something is wrong in my client code or server code. but since the problem never arises with firefox, i m inclined to think that it has smthing to do with either the network or with IE.
But if so what could i do to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922703