# How to detect PHP pfsockopen being closed by remote server?

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, tcp

I'm trying to make asynchronous HTTP POST requests from PHP server to an Nginx server. I read this very informative [blog post](https://segment.com/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/) about the issue, decided to use the technique with `pfsockopen` function, and imported the [code](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-php/blob/master/lib/Segment/Consumer/Socket.php) doing this written by the blog author. I include the key sections below:

```
private function createSocket() {
  if ($this->socket_failed)
    return false;
  $protocol = $this->ssl() ? "ssl" : "tcp";
  $host = $this->options["host"];
  $port = $this->ssl() ? 443 : 80;
  $timeout = $this->options["timeout"];
  try {
    # Open our socket to the API Server.
    # Since we're try catch'ing prevent PHP logs.
    $socket = @pfsockopen($protocol . "://" . $host, $port, $errno,
                         $errstr, $timeout);
    # If we couldn't open the socket, handle the error.
    if (false === $socket) {
      ...
      return false;
    }
    return $socket;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    ...
    return false;
  }
}

private function makeRequest($socket, $req, $retry = true) {
  $bytes_written = 0;
  $bytes_total = strlen($req);
  $closed = false;
  # Write the request
  while (!$closed && $bytes_written < $bytes_total) {
    try {
      # Since we're try catch'ing prevent PHP logs.
      $written = @fwrite($socket, substr($req, $bytes_written));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      ...
      $closed = true;
    }
    if (!isset($written) || !$written) {
      $closed = true;
    } else {
      $bytes_written += $written;
    }
  }
  # If the socket has been closed, attempt to retry a single time.
  if ($closed) {
    fclose($socket);
    if ($retry) {
      $socket = $this->createSocket();
      if ($socket) return $this->makeRequest($socket, $req, false);
    }
    return false;
  }
  $success = true;
  ...
  return $success;
}
```

It mostly works very well, but I'm observing the following problem. Usually, after about 30 seconds of inactivity, when I send a request this way, Nginx responds with a TCP RST (reset) packet, which [I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251243) indicates that the socket has been closed on the remote end. I can also see the connection statuses with `netstat -na | grep 8080` and by that time, the connection PHP -> Nginx is in state `CLOSE_WAIT`, while Nginx -> PHP is in `FIN_WAIT2`. [This guide](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajmi) confirms that this means the remote server wants to close the connection.

I know that the issue is caused by the connection timeout settings on the remote end, because when I increase it, connections shown by `netstat` remain in state `ESTABLISHED` for longer, and if PHP server decides to reuse such a connection, it works fine. However, I don't want to set connection timeout to a very high value, as I'm worried of running out of ports.

Is there any way I can detect in PHP that a connection went into a `CLOSE_WAIT` state? I tried the following and none of it works:

- Checking if handle returned by `pfsockopen` is false.
- Checking `$errno` variable written by `pfsockopen`.
- Try-catching exceptions from `pfsockopen` and `fwrite`.
- Checking if `fwrite($socket)` returns false.
- Checking if `fflush($socket)` returns false.
- Checking `stream_get_meta_data($socket)['timed_out']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the one-million question, from what I've read the only way to check that is doing `fread($socket)` and if returned value is false there has been an error, that could be millions of things but if the remote server has closed the connection the `fread` will always return false. Sorry if this disappoints you, but I think there's no other way.

Comment: Going once, going twice, sold! :) Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the best way is to select for read and, if readable, do an fread().

```
// $socket was opened via pfsockopen(...)
stream_set_blocking($socket,0);
while(1){
  // the do..while(0) is a trick to break out
  do{
     $rs = array($socket); $ws = NULL; $es = NULL;
     $ok = stream_select($rs,$ws,$es,0,100000);
     if ( $ok === false ) break; // select err, close and reconn
     if ( $ok <= 0 ) break 2; // select tout, conn is up/ok
     $rply = fread($socket,1024); // make one/two fread() 
     if ( $rply === false ) break; // read err
     if ( strlen($rply) == 0  ) break; // conn reset by peer
     break 2; // conn is up/ok
  }while(0); 
  // here i must reconn
  fclose($socket);
  $socket = pfsockopen(...);
  if ( $socket ) stream_set_blocking($socket,0);
  else return false;
  break;
}//endwhile1
// here the conn is up/ok
// check if some in $rply to be handled...
```