# the java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error

Tags: java

Only at the level of studies and take out doubts and curiosity. I would like to know how to fix this error

> java.net.SocketException Error: Connection reset.

How do you identify it?

Comment: This question does not seem to be asked very well, Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically what is detected by the exception is an error on the TCP level. Here is a question you might be interested in about the same topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251243/what-causes-a-tcp-ip-reset-rst-flag-to-be-sent)